# PyZX optimisation steps for Clifford circuits

Tags: programming, gate-synthesis, zx-calculus

Given the following ZX-diagram

[image]

It should represent some random Clifford circuit (LC means Local Clifford).

As far as I got, any Clifford circuit can be transformed into a ZX-diagram like the above, i.e. with depth 6, as stated [here](http://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2020-06-04-279/).
Authors also state that

> The part of the diagram marked $\mathcal{P}$ now has the form of a classical parity circuit.

So, this should mean that the set of edges in $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under (anti-)commutation.

If this is true I am interested to implementing this on the `PyZX` [framework](https://pyzx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). So, my question is: what are the implementation steps to reach this form?

Comment: Are you sure that diagram is correct? All those nodes have the same type so you can just repeatedly apply spider fusion until they're a single node.

Comment: Okay, looking at the slides, it seems like they're using some unstated convention where blue lines mean something different. Maybe they imply a hadamard but honestly it's hard to tell.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some kind of "eligibility" among all those blue lines.

Comment: I mean I think the point on that picture is indeed that you can still apply rules coming from ZX-calculus. They do similar observations in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00633.pdf. So maybe I can choose upon the rules which are more compliant to the architecture (doing so routing).

Comment: @CraigGidney I edited the question to a more basic one.

Comment: What do you mean the set of edges is closed under anti-commutation?

Comment: Also transforming these diagrams into circuits is already implemented in PyZX under the extract_circuit function, that can also deal with non-Clifford circuits.

Comment: When you say, "to reach this form" which form are you referring to? If the one on the left, then this is just the case of applying pyzx.cliff_simp, if the one on the right this is just a case of colour-changing the rightmost layer of spiders into red